# How to get the real and imaginary parts of a gabor kernel matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, iris-recognition

A OpenCV beginner and bad math.
My job is to apply the Gabor filter to a normalized image. And I only know that OpenCV has a `getGaborKernel` function, and i want to know the return Matrix of this function is the real part or the imaginary part of the kernel.
If I can't use this function, then how can I generate those kernel?
Using Java API, but C++ code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in [gabor.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/gabor.cpp) at line 87 that it's computing the **real** part (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter)).

```
double v = scale*std::exp(ex*xr*xr + ey*yr*yr)*cos(cscale*xr + psi);
```

You can get the imaginary part modifying this line to (as reported also [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/35740/getgaborkernel-and-complex-values/))

```
double v = scale*std::exp(ex*xr*xr + ey*yr*yr)*sin(cscale*xr + psi);
                                               ^^^
```

Once you have your kernel, you can use it with the function [filter2d](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#filter2d)

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: dear @Miki would you please take a look at my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218236/cluster-texture-based-on-features-extracted-from-gabor

Comment: @Miki >>Dear Miki no one has answered my question yet, I appreciate if you have the time now to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the difference between cos and sin is and offset of 90 degrees or PI/2.
So you can get the real and imaginary Gabor Kernels by making the PSI as 0 for real and PI/2 for imaginary.

> Mat kernelReal = getGaborKernel(ksize, sigma, theta, lambda, gamma, 0, 0, CV_32F);
>   Mat kernelImag = getGaborKernel(ksize, sigma, theta, lambda, gamma,0, PI/2, CV_32F);